# knowrob_cad_parser

Tags: knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
Please how can I install the **knowrob_cad_parser** package because it is important to the knowrob.
Regards
Ahmed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41004/knowrob_cad_parser/) by [Al-Moadhen](https://answers.ros.org/users/2139/al-moadhen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-08-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

please use the source installation [1] and update to the latest revision.

And please tag your question correctly (in this case with 'knowrob') so that I get an email notification.

best,
Moritz

[1] http://code.cs.tum.edu/pubsvn/knowrob/tags/latest/

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2012-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1